# QTimer basic program help

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to create a simple game that uses a timer but I can't seem to get it working. It throws this error: "no matching function for call to 'QObject::connect(QTimer*&, const char*, Time*&, const char*)'" now matter what I do do I can't fix it please help. I have only just started coding the game when I ran into this error. Here are the files exluding the unimportant(at the moment) qml file.

Main.cpp:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "qmlapplicationviewer.h"
#include "time.h"
#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QmlApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setOrientation(QmlApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationLockLandscape);
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("qml/RaakGame/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    Time *timmer = new Time;

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(0);
    QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), timmer, SLOT(ShowTime()));
    timer->start(1000);

    return app.exec();
}
```

time.h:

```
#ifndef TIME_H
#define TIME_H

class Time
{

public:
    Time();

private slots:
    void ShowTime();

signals:
    int setTime();

};
```

time.cpp:

```
#include "time.h"

int theTime = 60;

Time::Time()
{
    ShowTime();
}

void Time::ShowTime()
{
theTime--;
}

int Time::setTime()
{
    return theTime;
}

#endif // TIME_H
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your implementation of Time does not declare it to be a QObject, so you can't not connect slots or signals from it.  You need to inherit from QObject (or probably QWidget if you want to draw on the screen) and then include the statement `Q_OBJECT` which instantiates a few needed things.

```
class Time : public QWidget
{

Q_OBJECT

public:
    Time();

private slots:
    void ShowTime();

signals:
    int setTime();

};
```

Answer (score 1):

I notice that your classes do not contain the `Q_OBJECT` macro defined. This may help your efforts.

```
class Time
{
    Q_OBJECT

public Time() 
    .
    .
    .
}
```